# SQL Report Builder concatenate images and fields

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to display in a table cell the value of a field and an embedded image, I'm trying with this:

```
=Fields!page_navigation.Value & Image1.Value
```

but I'm receiving the message

```
Name 'Image1' is not declared
```

My image is outside the table and it's hidden, i just want it to appear next to the page navigation value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a text box will allow an embedded image, but its complaint is because the engine can't see where to find Image1 so you should try prefixing Image1 with a collection identifier, not sure which it is in reportbuilder, try Controls!Image1

Answer (score 0):

You can access `Image1.Value` through the built in collection `ReportItems`.

```
=Fields!page_navigation.Value & ReportItems!Image1.Value
```

More information about the `ReportItems` collection can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285.aspx).